# Removing unwanted part of a string message

Tags: java, json, string, filter, message

I have a message coming from a pressure sensor via TCP. The message looks as follows. It has a repetitive part and sensor data in json format. I want to remove the repetitive part from the message and extract only the json data part. Can someone help me to do this in java language?

**Repetitive part**

```
POST /V1.0/data.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: 124.43.5.212
User-Agent: RT-Thread HTTP Agent           
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 4349
```

**JSON data**

```
{
  "device": "0305170025",
  "Business": "0305170025",
  "version": "V1.0",
  "session": 1631171130,
  "command": "send_server_measure",
  "content": {
    "measure": [
      {
        "name": "press",
        "datatype": "float",
        "content": [
          {
            "t": 1631169540,
            "v": 9901
          },
          {
            "t": 1631169550,
            "v": 9901
          },
          {
            "t": 1631169560,
            "v": 9901
          },
          {
            "t": 1631171130,
            "v": 9901
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a Minimum Viable Exaple?

Comment: Can you update the problem with more information and what you've tried to solve it!

Comment: Repetitive part is nothing but HTTP headers(which will be sent by server). How are you consuming service currently?

Comment: I need to remove this part to save the data in to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward solution

```java
String message = "<your message with header and json body>";
String json = message.substring(message.indexOf('{'));
```

Comment: I tried this. but still no luck. there is a empty space between http header and json data.is that a problem?

Comment: while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
                String content = sb.toString();
                //System.out.println(content);
                String jsn=content.substring(content.indexOf("{"));
                System.out.println(jsn);

Comment: @Yushanthachathuranga from what source are you reading (`br.readLine()`)?

Comment: ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4000);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String line;